# creating a button filter wordpress custom theme

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm new in the php language, I have to create some buttons that have to filter / show some posts of certain categories but without the page being reloaded. So I know it's possible to use a function with php and ajax but I don't understand how to call ajax and what to write.[The result should be this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLau1.jpg)

Comment: Hi Francesco. There are several approaches. But indeed you can use PHP and vanilla JavaScript to create the effect. Here is a really simple example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp Obviously, in order to help you out more, you would need to provide code examples.

Answer (score 0):

So with php you can only send requests to the server to filter the posts causing a reload of the page. What you want is an instant filter, that gets all the data first and then, for example with javascript, filter this already loaded posts by category / taxonomy.

Doing this with Vue.js is pretty easy. Why use Vue js? You can simply add it with one line of code to your wordpress page.

I assume, you are now in your **archive.php** inside of the folder of your theme.
Put this code below the get_header() ?> and make vue available on your page:

```
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

You can find the production code here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ If you don't need the console warnings for debugging.

I now give you the code and will explain after that. With the follwing code in your archive.php (in the main container of your archive page), you put a link which toggles a div container with the filter buttons. The buttons are all your categories, if you click them, the posts will be filtered:

```
<div id="filtered_posts">
    <span class="filter_button" v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden">Filter by Category</span>
    <div class="filters" v-if="!isHidden">
        <span class="filter" :class="{ active: currentFilter === '' }" v-on:click="setFilter('')">All</span>
        <span class="filter" :class="{ active: currentFilter === category.id }" v-on:click="setFilter(category.id)" v-for="category in categories">{{ category.name }}</span>
    </div>

    <transition-group id="archive" class="categories" name="categories" >
        <div v-if="currentFilter === post.categories['0'] || currentFilter === ''" v-bind:key="post.title.rendered" v-for="post in posts">
            <a v-bind:href="post.link"><img v-bind:src="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url"></a>
            <a v-bind:href="post.link"><h4 v-html="post.name"></h4></a>
            <p class="smaller" v-html="post.title.rendered"></p>
    </div>
    </transition-group>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/filter.js"></script>
```

So what we are doing here is we make an container (#filtered_posts) and put the link to toggle the filter buttons. After that there are the filter buttons inside of the div with the .filters class. The first span is for resetting to all posts, the second span circles through your categories (done by vue js for you) the call the setFilter() function on click.

The transition-group is used for a nice transition animation we add later. Here you check your current set filter in the if and circle through your posts, done by v-for="post in posts", as we did it with the categories before. We output some values by using the wp rest api fields, calling them with a dot followed by the name.

At the end we include a javascript file. And there we get the data to be displayed.

Please now create a folder in your theme folder called "js" and put an empty filter.js file in it.

You get now the code for the filter.js file, which you are getting in the archive.php file with the script tag.

```
new Vue({
el: '#filtered_posts',
data: {
    currentFilter: '',
    categories: [],
    posts: [],
    isHidden: true,
},
mounted() {
    fetch("https://yourWordpressURLhere.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            this.categories = data;
        })
    fetch("https://yourWordpressURLhere.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&_embed=wp:term,wp:featuredmedia")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data => {
            this.posts= data;
        }))
},

methods: {
    setFilter: function (filter) {
        this.currentFilter = filter;
    }
}
});
```

We are creating a vue instance and set it to the element with the id "filtered_posts", so its the container wrapping our code from before.
We now create some data objects to save data in it for the categories, the posts, the current filter and an isHidden for the toggle of the filter buttons.

We mount some data via api from wordpress. Please use the URL of your wordpress page. Make sure you have https to make it work. We are saving the recieved data into our "categories" and "posts" objects.

The setFilter function gets the current filter via parameter and sets it for this element.

We only have to set some CSS now, please add to your style.css of your theme:

```
.categories {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.categories-enter {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translatey(-80px);
        transform: scale(0.5) translatey(-80px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.categories-leave-to {
    -webkit-transform: translatey(30px);
    transform: translatey(30px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.categories-leave-active {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

With this CSS code, you have nice transitions when clicking your filter buttons.

You are now all set up, should get your categories in clickable buttons, which filter the output underneath.

There is a lot more to explain about this code, but I think the post is already long enough. If you ask in the comments, I will add more information if needed.

Hope this gives you a smooth and easy starting point for filtering posts with vue js with no reload.